# jQuery Knob Apply Inner Colour

Tags: jquery, css

I am wondering if anyone knows how to change [jQuery Knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) Inner Circle background colour?

```
<script>
    $(function($) {
        $(".knob").knob({
            //'readOnly':true,
            'fgColor':"#238eb1",
            'bgColor':'#1b1b1b'
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="nob">
            <input class="knob" data-bgColor="#fff" data-width="200" data-max="1499" data-displayPrevious=true value="1250">
        </div>
```

Comment: I think perhaps if you set up your code (or a demo) in jsFiddle; it might be easier for you to get a good answer to this question.

Comment: i think you might have to change your parent background, i mean where you are generating circles

Comment: Can you provide `.knob`'s html?

Comment: for those interested: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/
the docs doesn't mention anything about inner colour

Comment: I just need change jQuery knob background inside the circle to different colour.

Comment: I know it doesnt provide inner colour this why I am asking if anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: hey check the new answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
.parentElement {
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This is what I did before you posted this :)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up editing the jquery.knob.js file directly (starting from line 764):

```
if (this.o.bgColor !== "none") {

            c.beginPath();
            c.strokeStyle = this.o.bgColor;
            c.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius, this.endAngle - 0.00001, 
            this.startAngle + 0.00001, true);

            c.fillStyle="#fff";         // Added code to make the inner circle white
            c.fill();                   // Added code to make the inner circle white

            c.stroke();
        }
```

You just need to make sure the 'fill' occurs before the 'stroke'.

Comment: I changed your added code to: `if (this.o.innerBg) {  c.fillStyle = this.o.innerBg;  c.fill();  }`. Then, you can call `$('.knob').knob({  innerBg: '#fff'  })`.

Answer (score 0):

check following code:

```
$(".knob").knob({
    'fgColor': 'red',
    'bgColor': '#ccc000',
});
```

or check following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/itskawsar/6BYhF/2/

i think it will help.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go...thanks GoDataFeed!

```
$(".knob").trigger("configure", { fgColor: color }).css("color",color);
```